# joosy forms don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, joosy

I follow guide http://guides.joosy.ws/guides/blog/forms.html and try to create forms for new and edit post

So I create `templates/pages/posts/_form.jst.hamlc` with form and add code in `pages/posts/new.js.coffee`:

```
Joosy.namespace 'Posts', ->

  class @NewPage extends ApplicationPage
    @layout ApplicationLayout
    @view   'new'

  elements:
    'rawForm': 'form'

  @fetch (complete) ->
    @data.post = Post.build()
    complete()

  @afterLoad ->
    @form = Joosy.Form.attach @rawForm,
      resource: @data.post
      success: (data) => @navigate '/'
```

But "inner magic" doesn't work for me.. When I follow `http://localhost:3000/blog#!/posts/new` I see form for new post. This form submits as usual form. I.e. if I type something and press Save, it opens new page `http://localhost:3000/blog?post%5Btitle%5D=test&post%5Bbody%5D=test#!/posts`

So, I've stopped on this step and have no ideas what to do with that..

P.S. If you can retag this question to 'joosy' please do it. Author promises to answer questions about joosy framework [here](http://borisstaal.com/post/24401343976/joosy-alternative-approach-to-browser-frameworks) by 'joosy' tag, but I can't create this tag due to lack of reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check three things:

1. Check console for overall errors. It may fail before afterLoad. And this is javascript which just dies silently unless you watch errors.
2. Try to add console.log @rawForm in your afterLoad to ensure you get the correct DOM element binded.
3. Try to compare your code with working example: https://github.com/roundlake/joosy-example

And if 1/2 didn't work and you don't have much time, show me your template either cause this pages looks like a copy of this one: https://github.com/roundlake/joosy-example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/blog/pages/posts/new.js.coffee. But the latter is known to work. So trouble is not here.

Comment: Omg, it was my bad :) I set wrong indents in coffee. Thank you!